# renaming 6000 files with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to rename 6000 files to a given name.

Below is what I've tried to do but it didn't work.

```
C:\>for /l %f in (1,1,6000) do rename C:\Temp\1Filename.mp4 C:\Temp\%fFilename.txt
```

Comment: You'll end up renaming the original file to the new name on first pass, then the original file wont be there to rename on the second.  Try copying the files instead of renaming.

Comment: Do I understand it right? You have files 1Filename.mp4 to 6000Filename.mp4 and you want to rename them all from .mp4 to .txt?

Comment: `for %A in (C:\Temp\*.mp4) do ren "%~fA" "%~nA.txt"`

Comment: yea MichealS i want to rename "1filename mp4 to 6000filename to a specified 6000 names i have. so basically the whole 6000file wouldhave a different name

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more info (specify your goal). If I can understand (see my answer): rename all  `1*.mp4` files with leading `1` in name (e.g. `1x.mp4` to  `6000x.mp4`,  `1abc.mp4` to  `6000abc.mp4` etc.).  I could guess only your another conceivable target: for a given string (e.g. `fixedpart`), rename all  `*.mp4` files  to names like `1fixedpart.mp4` , `2fixedpart.mp4`,  ..., `3251fixedpart.mp4` up to 6000 (or until all files renamed?). I could guess only...

Comment: JosefZ the leading "1.......6000" are actually not on the file names i just used that for more and easy clarification. they are just 6000 files with different names that need to be changed that all. so would like to know if the script you wrote down there would work?

Answer (score 0):

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (C:\Temp\1*.mp4) do (
  set "fullName=%%~fA"
  set "oldName=%%~nxA"
  call :rname
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:rname
rem remove first character
set "newName=%oldName:~1%"
echo rename "%fullName%" "6000%newName%" 
goto :eof
```

Notes:

- Consider testing a file existence before `rename`.
- The `rename` command `echo`ed merely for debugging purposes; remove leading `echo` no sooner than debugged...

**Resources** (required reading):

- `~` argument modifier: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)

Comment: so to be very sure, JosefZ, the script above would pick the whole 1 - 6000 files one by one and rename them?